# ¿Por qué llamar directamente al hook useState conduce a un bucle infinito?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Soy nuevo en el uso de React. Intenté hacer un contador sencillo en un functional component, donde uso el hook de useState para aumentar en 1 el valor del contador cada vez que presiono el botón +1. Resulta que llamar a `setCounter` directamente al hacer click en el botón de aumentar conduce a un error porque "la página se re-renderiza infinitamente", mientras que llamarlo como callback(o sea, `() => setCounter()`) renderiza el componente correctamente, sin caer en un bucle de re-renderizado infinito

```js
import { useState } from "react"

export const CounterApp = () => {

    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(10)

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Counter: {counter}</h1>

            <hr />

            <button onClick={setCounter(counter + 1)}>+1</button> //Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders.React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
            <button onClick={ () => setCounter(counter + 1)}>+1</button> //Renderiza correctamente

        </>
    )
}
```

Quisiera saber por qué ocurre esto del re-renderizado infinito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto ocurre por que en el evento onClick de tu boton estas directamente ejecutando la funcion setCounter(), por lo que cuando se renderiza tu componente se ejecuta de inmediato setCounter(counter + 1) que a su vez ejecuta otra vez el renderizado del componente al modificarse tu counter y asi infinitamente.

En cambio en tu segundo boton ***estas entregando la declaracion de una funcion al evento onClick sin ejecutarla***, por lo que esta se ejecutara solo al ejecutarse el evento onClick de tu boton.

Saludos.

Lectura recomendada:
https://es.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html